# Rewrite Rule - MVC - OOP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi guys i'm trying to apply a rule on my htaccess :

I made a MVC framework (OOP)  in php .

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ ?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ ?module=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Where module is the name of the controller and action is the function of the controller.

Example of url : http://mywebsite.com/ads/sell

How can i write http://mywebsite.com/contact instead of http://mywebsite.com/page/contact with a rule in my htaccess.

I dont have a router class

Comment: Add this before all rules: `RewriteRule ^contact/?$ ?module=page&action=contact [L]`

Comment: @revo thx it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ ?module=page&action=$1 [L]
```

comment if have any error issue